# Send SOAP Request from a specific IP address

Tags: vb.net, soap, asmx

I have a system with multiple IP address. But I'm allowed to initiate SOAP Request only from one IP address. How do I obtain that in VB.NET.

Comment: Web Reference or Service Reference?

Answer (score 2):

I've never done this. It looks complicated.

First, read [Ways to Customize your ASMX Client Proxy](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2008/06/05/ways-to-customize-your-asmx-client-proxy/) to learn the basic technique of overriding the `GetWebRequest` object of your proxy class.

You will need to override `GetWebRequest` so that you can grab the `ServicePoint` being used to make the request. You will set the [`BindIPEndPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.bindipendpoint.aspx) property to a delegate pointing to a method of yours which will return the correct IP Address.

```
public partial class Service1
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) base.GetWebRequest(uri);
        request.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate = ReturnSpecificIPAddress;
        return request;
    }

    private IPEndPoint BindIPEndPoint(
        ServicePoint servicePoint,
        IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint,
        int retryCount)
    {
        return new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("10.0.0.1"), 80);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In WCF when you create your ChannelFactory you can specify your endpoint (or IP address to which you wish to connect).

```
 Dim factory As ChannelFactory(Of IChatServiceChannel)
 factory = New DuplexChannelFactory(Of IChatServiceChannel)(callbackObject, binding, endpoint)
 Dim Channel = factory.CreateChannel()
```

You can connect to as many different IPs as you want like this by specifying different endpoints.

Comment: not the end point but the starting point for SOAP request initialization. @RyanFishman

Comment: Besides, he says he's using a web reference, so he can't use your technique.